# How to hide the main tool bar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I hide the Main tool bar and make the Render Widget fullscreen.

This is the current image of how it looks like ,  I want  to remove the top tool bar and show the widget which has been promoted to opengl fullscreen.

[image]

this is the current code.

```
void Renderer::FullScreen()
{
    if (!fullScreen)
    {
        widgetRender->setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1024);        
        mainToolBar->hide();
        fullScreen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        widgetRender->setGeometry(960, 500, 960, 512);
        fullScreen = false;
    }
}
```

mainToolBar->hide() does not hide the Main tool bar.

Comment: you should write this `mainToolBar->setVisible(false);`

Comment: Parisa.H.R still the main tool bar does not hide after this line of code.

Comment: You are trying to hide the menuBar() and not the toolbar.

Comment: I try `ui->menubar->setVisible(false);` and it works . I use MainWindow and its default menubar.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R thanks it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling the method setVisible(bool) should be more than ok
example:

```
ui->mainToolBar->setVisible(false);
```

[image]